# Entity Framework Code First Inheritance - multiple types

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i'm using Entity Framework Code First Table-per-Type Inheritance. I want to model this issue:

I've got one base class called: User. And two derived classes:

**public class Student : User{} 

public class Teacher : User {}**

So now I want to be able to insert a User that is a Teacher and also a Student. As far I know this is not possible in this approach. So how can I solve this in Code First ? And how would a sample insert look like ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: An alternative would be to have interfaces `IStudent` and `ITeacher`, but again, you'd need to know at compile time. You could perhaps have a base `User` table and then `StudentDetails` and `TeacherDetails` that foregin-key back to `User`. When a user becomes a student, fill in their `StudentDetails`. When they become a teacher, fill in their `TeacherDetails`. If they end up being a student and a teacher, they'll have references in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You guess you need to create another class called `public class TeachingStudent: User` and use it for such cases

Comment: thx. But it only partially solves my problem. Because i have to know at the beginnig that this student will teach. I want to have more flexible solution.

Comment: When student will go teaching you can remove it from Students and add it to TeachingStudents